# Not receiving any emails

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.1 and I am testing the emails that are being sent when customers place orders.

I have gone into the admin and made sure that I have entered a valid Store Email, made sure that `New Order Alert Mail:` is set to Yes.

Whenever I make an order (I am using Barclays ePDQ) I place the order, but as a customer I receive no order email. The store owner also doesn't seem to be sent.

I get nothing in the error.log file `system/log` I also have nothing in the `vqmod.log` file.

I am completely stumped as to why these emails are not sending.

I have checked the spam folders of both the customer and the store owner.

Looking at the maillog on the server, there are no records suggesting the email has been sent (this could be why the emails are not being received), but this doesn't explain why the emails are simply not being sent.

The order is listed in admin under `Sales->Orders`, just no emails.

Thanks

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Comment: emails work fine for me on all versions of 1.5.X. I would recommend contacting your host and asking if they can check if the "mail" method is available, and running correctly, or if you need to enter SMTP details. It also might be due to the "extra parameter" that some systems require/won't accept. See the MAIL tab under SYSTEM > SETTINGS in your admin for more info

Comment: The server is a rackspace box running Plesk. So we have a few sites running on using mail() fine. Could the problem be that the domain  running the store is `www.exampleshop.com` and the store email is sales@example.com? example.com is run on another server, whilst www.exampleshop.com is running on the Plesk based server

Comment: That shouldn't matter either to be honest. If you do order status updates with notification, do they go through at all?

Comment: I get: `Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The fifth parameter is disabled in SAFE MODE in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/system/library/mail.php on line 154`

Comment: In plesk under PHP Support, safe_mode was checked. That has just wasted 2 hours of my life!!!!!!!

Comment: hehe plesk can be a nightmare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in Plesk when setting up/editting a domain that under `PHP Support`, make sure that `safe_mode` is left unchecked.

This will cause nothing but complete frustration.